# Arduino DualShock 4 C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to control an Arduino uno board using a DualShock 4(PS4). I'm having difficulty programming the joysticks `PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY)` I want to control a motor using the joystick; I want the motor to go forward when I press up(`++i`), backward when I press down(`--i`), and no speed when I don't move the joystick. I'm able to move the motor in one direction and the speed increases but I can't get the other direction to work. I can't seem make a connection between the joystick values `(PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) > 137 || PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) < 117)` and the motor values (`0` - `255`).

I'm using a USB Shield and a Motor Shield.

I need help figuring out the first if statement.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
if (PS4.connected()) 
{
    if (PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) > 137)
    {
        M3->setSpeed(255)); 
        PS4.setLed(Green);
        PS4.setLedFlash(100 ,100);
    }
}
```

I want the value for M3 to increase as I increase joystick angle:

```
for (int i=0; i<=255; ++i)
    M3->setSpeed(i);
```

Comment: if (PS4.connected())
  {
    if ( PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) > 137 || PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) < 117)
    {
      M3->setSpeed(PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));          
      PS4.setLed(Green);
      PS4.setLedFlash(100 ,100);     
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the condition of `min(117)` and `max(137)` tolerance to move motor. And then, map the posibles values of joystick to the range of motor's speed

```
if (PS4.connected()) 
{
    int analogValue = PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY);
    if (analogValue  > 137 || analogValue < 117)
    {
        int motorValue = y = map(x, 117, 137 , 0, 255); 
        M3->setSpeed(motorValue); 
        PS4.setLed(Green);
        PS4.setLedFlash(100 ,100);
    }
}
```

It could be better with some error handling but you could start with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 uint16_t s = PS4.getAnalogHat(RightHatY);

if (PS4.getAnalogHat(RightHatY) < 117 )
{
 s = map (s, 117,  0, 0, 250);
 M3->run(FORWARD);
 M3->setSpeed(s);
 PS4.setLed(Green);
 PS4.setLedFlash(100, 100);
}

if (PS4.getAnalogHat(RightHatY) > 137)
{
 s = map (s, 137, 0, 0, -250);
 M3->run(BACKWARD);
 M3->setSpeed(s);
 PS4.setLed(Green);
 PS4.setLedFlash(100, 100);
}
```

This is the solution to the problem I originally asked. Variable speed control of a motor using a Dualshock 4 & Arduino Motor shield. Thanks a lot for the help. I was 3d Printing parts for the robot/chassis which is why I took time off programming.